# Elegant way to track changed attributes in RactiveJS

Tags: javascript, attributes, nested, components, ractivejs

Looking for a way/suggestions on tracking changed attributes/data in a Ractive instance. I've tried using observers and maintaining changed values in a separate object, but the keypath is generally not the full keypath when the observer is called -- so tracking changes on nested objects becomes a bit of a hassle.

Any other ways to handle this?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about your use case? `ractive.observe(...)` is usually the best way to do this sort of thing, and you can use patterns (like `ractive.observe('items.*.active', (n,o,k,index) => {...})` to observe many things at once

Comment: Yeah, I could definitely just comma delimit the fields I suppose for the observe. I have a rather complex modeling of an item for sale and the use case is is that I want an administrator to have the ability to edit many facets of that sale. So instead of declaring .observe() on 'sale.product.attributes.title' I was wondering if there was a more generic way to observe changes but get the granularity of the keypath.

I'd like to be able to keep track of specific changes made to that model and avoid sending the whole model out to a service for updating.